# Please Contact Your Hosting Provider To Ensure The Appropriate Security Settings Have Been Enabled On The Server

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using Text/HTML module. I Click on Edit Text, Then i click on Image icon to insert image, Then i click on Browse Serve at Image Info tab, then i click on Browse button, then i click on Upload New File which result in below error :

An Error Has Occurred When Attempting To Save The File F:\Newgen\DNN\DotNetNuke_Community_04.09.05_Source\Website\Portals\0\1365-little-cutie.jpg. Please Contact Your Hosting Provider To Ensure The Appropriate Security Settings Have Been Enabled On The Server.

Please suggest which permission i have to made on folder. Also specify folder name ie website or Portal\0.

If I am creating a folder using DNN, then uploading new file in this folder, then its working fine. All the rights has been assigned to Website folder which have this new folder. Please suggest.

I am using DNN 4.09.05/ Windows XP Version 2002, Service Pack 3/ IIS V5.1

Answer (score 1):

You should have permissions on the F:\Newgen\DNN\DotNetNuke_Community_04.09.05_Source\Website\ folder for the ASPNET worker process, it should have Modify or Full Control and that permission should be propagated down to all child folders.